How to use lock an object and use async in the method in MailKit (C#)?
If you use some MailKit method and have some concurrent access on the API, you will get an InvalidOperationException exception like this:

The ImapClient is currently busy processing a command in another thread. Lock the SyncRoot property to properly synchronize your threads.

You would normally do, as it's suggested by the error message:
lock (imapClient.SyncRoot)
{
    imapClient.GetFolder(/* ... */)
}

However, if you do want to keep everything that is possible to use in an async way, you'd do:
lock (imapClient.SyncRoot)
{
    await imapClient.GetFolderAsync(/* ... */)
}

This does not work/compile, because of CS1996 (direct link), because:

An await expression can't be used in the scope of a lock statement.

I already read and found many issues regarding this topic, but the best solution is still unclear to me. If this is fundamentally incompatible, how is the async Mailkit API supposed to be used? And why does it suggest .SyncRoot if that is fundamentally incompatible with that approach?
What's the best practice here?

Related: Lock and Async method in C#.

Rather than using locking, can you not let one singleton component own the imap client and then have anything else that wants things to happen with it do that via putting requests in a queue?

Why you need to share the client by concurrent Tasks and then need to serialize again to work after another? First thing i would look at is coding it in a way not needing that but having a client per task and not a shared one. You can't do anything in parallel on a connection anyways.

@Ralf The concurrency is not really intended, actually. It's more of e.g. when the application closes and does a Disconnect another request may still be running. But yeah, spawning one client for each mail processed e.g. may be possible, though possibly a little bit too much too change.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever Implementing a queue for each method it has is AFAIK a bit too much work, I guess. (Also MailKit could implement that so not everyone using it would have to.)

The only easy to implement solution I found was using SemaphoreSlim like suggested here. It's also the general solution to the problem.
It can e.g. be implemented via inheritance to the ImapClient:
using MailKit.Net.Imap;

/// <remarks>
/// Using multiple instances of <see cref="MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient"/> to connect to the same mailbox at the same time is very likely to cause issues.
/// This is because an IMAP server simply refuses to take new commands when it is currently busy executing another command. To make a single ImapClient instance
/// accessible throughout the app, to be used by multiple concurrent Tasks, we can restrict access to it by using a semaphore that can be locked and released
/// before and after using the ImapClient.
/// </remarks>
/// <inheritdoc cref="ImapClient"/>
public interface IImapClientWithSemaphore : IImapClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <b>Always</b> wait for the semaphore before executing any relevant command. See <see cref="IImapClientWithSemaphore"/> for a detailed explanation on why.
    /// </summary>
    public SemaphoreSlim Semaphore { get; }
}

Implemented like this:
/// <inheritdoc cref="IImapClientWithSemaphore"/> />
public class ImapClientWithSemaphore : ImapClient, IImapClientWithSemaphore
{
    /// <inheritdoc cref="IImapClientWithSemaphore"/> />
    public SemaphoreSlim Semaphore { get; } = new(1, 1);

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ImapClient"/> />
    public ImapClientWithSemaphore() { }

    /// <inheritdoc cref="ImapClient"/> />
    public ImapClientWithSemaphore(IProtocolLogger protocolLogger) : base(protocolLogger) { }
}

You can then just do this:
await imapClient.Semaphore.WaitAsync(CancellationToken.None);

try
{
    await imapClient.GetFolderAsync(/* ... */)
}
finally
{
    imapClient.Semaphore.Release();
}

